# How can I switch the application default form to a new form in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, desktop-application, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm try making an app whereby when I click on **login page** it will be moved to my ***dashboard*** and close the login page. This is to reduce its load and make my dashboard the default running app. Can anybody provide advice?

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: Who on earth up-voted this?  Both up-voter and OP need to refresh themselves perhaps with [ask]

Comment: I'm trying to add an event handler to the close button in my app but when i use Form closing and form closed event it will automatically work when i switched to another form from my working form . I just want to invoke my function on close icon click button.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, put a property IsLoginOk in LoginForm and use it like this:

```
  bool isLoginOk;
  using (var loginForm = new LoginForm())
  {
    // start login form and will be closed if user click OK
    loginForm.ShowDialog();
    isLoginOk = loginForm.IsLoginOk;
  }

  // if login ok, then start dashboard, and login form is closed and disposed
  if (isLoginOk)
  {
    Application.Run(new DashboardForm());
  }
```